# The sexy zombie outbreak

Tags: society, modern-age, zombies, sex

Tomorrow hordes of zombies will invade the streets around the world caused by an airborne fungus. The disease is incurable and the symptoms are similar to rabies.

These zombies try to infect and engage in sexual relationships with anyone in sight. When no humans are near they arrange a massive orgy with each other. The incubation period is 30 minutes to 1 hour.

With some time the fungus starts growing around the sexual organs making them bigger and granting its host super strength and virulent airborne pheromones that attract their prey.

**The fungus mostly infects women. Infection rates in men are 5 %. Behaviour is the same, regardless of the age.**

**How much disruption and chaos can my outbreak cause? What are the weaknesses and strengths of my zombie girls?**

Note: Fast zombies. They still have some intelligence. Let's say New York City is overrun to make this more interesting and the zombies eat humans only when they are hungry. When they are not they have sex with each other or they try to force a healthy human.

Comment: Only infects women but 20% of men is infected? That's contradiction. Also, "instant" incubation is so much impossible that you could pretty much write anything, seems your reader ls are willing to ignore reason.

Comment: Your punctuation is very strange.  Why do you use a comma instead of a period+space?

Comment: «How would everyone react?» is primary opinion based.  «What are the pros and cons of my zombies?» doesn’t make sense — are you weighing a decision of some kind?

Comment: I suggest doing a Google search on "rabies symptoms". Since symptoms include "Also common: anxiety, brain death, coma, difficulty swallowing, dilated pupil, drooling, excess salivation, headache, mental confusion, seizures, or stiff neck". These alone might constitute weaknesses in zombie girls.

Comment: @a4android Is not rabies,I just like the white foam symptom.

Comment: I know it's not rabies. You said the symptoms are similar to rabies. There are more symptoms than simply foaming at the mouth.

Comment: We have a [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on Meta. You can post your first draft of a question there as an answer to that post and wait a bit for feedback. That way we can help you with the general stuff like punctuation(!), grammar, choice of words, on-topic/off-topic, ... before you release the question onto the Main Site. This might be helpful for you for future questions as you changed your question 6 times in the last 3 hours. Plus there are two revisions from a4android and me.

Comment: The top 1% of sexiest, most beautiful zombies manages to infect 95% of the male population in three days, even if the ratio of infection is just 5%. :D

Comment: Another "High Concept, Do My Work For Me" question. Three big problems with the question: 1) This is not so much world building as it is story building. 2) It is very broad and entirely opinion-based. 3) You are asking us to do your work for you. Ok, so you came up with a concept... zombies that screw instead of kill. That is the start of a story, even possibly a world if taken to its extreme far end. But **you** need to write this story/build this world. If you just show up here saying "Here is the concept, now tell me all the consequences of that, ok, thanks, bye"... nope, not good.

Comment: We are here to help you when you get **stuck**; whenever you have a **problem** that provides a road block for you in your creative process. You can even ask some creative catalysts that might add flavour, or take your existing work further, deeper or in an entirely different direction. But the thing is: **you have no problem here, you are not stuck**. You have just invented the concept and then gone **nowhere** with it. So I suggest that you start working on this on your own, and if then you run into obstacles, that is when you ask here and we will be sure to help you. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question - story based; seeking for plot; not enough information provided.

Comment: 2 questions: Conservation of energy and mass; 1)Sexual organs increase in size...where does the additional mass come from? Also which sexual organs, exactly? A woman's womb doubling in size isn't particularly useful. 2) If they're fast and horny, they'll be burning through a lot of calories. Where does the energy come from? And I'm not even taking the energy for "growth of sexual organs" into account.

Comment: @JDługosz His punctuation is strange because this user is the same user as the person who posted [this meta apology](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4821/my-public-apology-to-the-wb-community) (Previously known as Alex Darkshine or something like that) - the first comment of the meta apology actually mentions his punctuation and how we've repeatedly told him it's wrong.

Answer (score 8):

I'm torn whether this is a legitimate question, but on the chance it is: Insofar as their sexual tendencies go, I would think there's nothing particularly special about your zombies being horny rapists, per se. The super strength and pheromones obviously are beneficial to the zombies, making it easier to catch their prey. But in the end, whether they're standard fare, mindless brain-munchers, or intelligent, sex-crazed undead, eventually you're gonna get eaten. Your zombies just apparently like to play with their food, first.

To your question, common sense suggests that the young and the old are easier prey than healthy adults. Unless, of course, the adult is aroused by those pheromones beyond the point of reason.

Basically, the zombies' nemesis would be a vengeful eunuch in his 20s.

Comment: ...especially if the pheromones still work on him